How to get all selected table row items in React?
I have component with table of items. I would like to select few items and be able to do some operation on selected items when i click button under table.
My main table component:
export default function TableComp() {
    function handleSelectedRows() {...}
return (
    <Table>
        ...
        {items.map(item => (
           <TableRowItem item={item}></TableRowItem>
        ))}
    </Table>
    <Button onClick={handleSelectedRows}/>
)}

My TableRowItem component:
function TableRowItem({item}) {
    const [active, setActive] useState(false);
    function handleCLick() {
        setActive(!active);
    }
    return (
        <TableRow onClick={handleCLick} active={active}>...</TableRow>
    )
}

How I could know from Table component what rows was selected?
I could put selected items to the store, but is there any other proper way to get them?

You can store the selected row keys in a state.
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState<number[]>([]);

  console.log('selectedRowKeys: ', selectedRowKeys);
  const items = Array.from({ length: 10 }).map((_, i) => ({
    id: i,
  }));

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {items.map((item) => {
          const findIndex = selectedRowKeys.findIndex((k) => k === item.id);
          return (
            <tr
              style={{ background: findIndex > -1 ? 'green' : 'transparent' }}
              key={item.id}
              onClick={() => {
                if (findIndex > -1) {
                  setSelectedRowKeys(
                    selectedRowKeys.filter((k) => k !== item.id)
                  );
                } else {
                  setSelectedRowKeys([...selectedRowKeys, item.id]);
                }
              }}
            >
              <td>{item.id}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

export default App;

stackblitz

My React Table Component you can handle selecting table rows by maintaining state to track which rows are selected. Here's a basic example of how you can achieve this:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MyTable() {
    const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

    const handleRowClick = (rowId) => {
        // Check if the row is already selected
        const selectedIndex = selectedRows.indexOf(rowId);
        let newSelectedRows = [];

        if (selectedIndex === -1) {
            // If not selected, add it to the array
            newSelectedRows = [...selectedRows, rowId];
        } else {
            // If already selected, remove it from the array
            newSelectedRows = selectedRows.filter(id => id !== rowId);
        }

        // Update the state with the new selected rows
        setSelectedRows(newSelectedRows);
    };

    // Function to handle getting all selected row items
    const getAllSelectedItems = () => {
        // Assuming your table data is stored in some array called 'tableData'
        const selectedItems = selectedRows.map(rowId => {
            // Assuming each row has a unique id and its data is stored in an object
            return tableData.find(row => row.id === rowId);
        });

        return selectedItems;
    };

    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {tableData.map(row => (
                    <tr key={row.id} onClick={() => handleRowClick(row.id)}>
                        <td>{row.id}</td>
                        <td>{row.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => console.log(getAllSelectedItems())}>Get Selected Items</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyTable;

